# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given | mysql |mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have code like this in mysql_query , works fine. 
but i moving all the code to mysqli_ its throw error like in the title

mysql

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx limit 2") or die(mysql_error());
      $count = mysql_result($count,0);
      for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
        echo '<li data-target="#transition-timer-carousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"'; if($i==0){ echo 'class="active"'; } echo '></li>';
      }
```

mysqli

```
   $count = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx limit 2") or die(mysqli_error());
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($count,0);
      for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
        echo '<li data-target="#transition-timer-carousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"'; if($i==0){ echo 'class="active"'; } echo '></li>';
      }
```

pls help ..
editt.
this code for

work : http://www.imagebam.com/image/830cf2469802470 in mysql_

not working : i already did the mysqli_num_rows ($count); http://www.imagebam.com/image/a32c87469802459

this code for counting this : http://www.imagebam.com/image/f8a0b9469803871 see the red

Comment: its better way to read manual , to know whats happening in functions !

Comment: `COUNT` will return an integer with the number of rows, and `mysqli_num_rows` (if called with the correct parameters) will count *the number of integers returned* (one), not the number of rows. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) does nothing even remotely similar to [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php).

The replacement for `mysql_result` in mysqli in this case would be to fetch the entire row and use the first element only, something like;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx limit 2") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];

for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
    echo '<li data-target="#transition-timer-carousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"'; if($i==0){ echo 'class="active"'; } echo '></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

you must change `$count = mysqli_num_rows($count,0);` into `$count = mysqli_num_rows($count);`

**NOTE**:Don't use mysql any more.This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0

Comment: i alredy do dat pls see the link mysql work http://www.imagebam.com/image/830cf2469802470 , not work mysqli http://www.imagebam.com/image/a32c87469802459

Comment: what you exactly want? with this query ? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx limit 2`

Comment: Try to edit your question , don't put too much link !

Comment: @RamaDiansyahS if you have image , or other things that you think that can help to make better answer , try to add them into your question .

Answer (score 0):

this error throws because PHP function

```
 int mysqli_num_rows ( mysqli_result $result )
```

needs only one argument.

Here is 
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php
documentation

Answer (score -2):

correct way of doing is

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx limit 2";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```